# Do These Tasks in order - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to do these 3 tasks in order
how could i do it?
using Async/await or promises or any other way

```
// task 1 
ctx.telegram.sendMessage(MasterID, `⭐⭐⭐new order⭐⭐⭐`)

// task 2
for (var key in pricetag) {
  if (pricetag.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if ((pricetag[key] * ctx.session.quantity[key]) != 0) {

      ctx.reply(`" ${key} " , " ${ctx.session.quantity[key]} " |  " ${ctx.session.totalprice[key].format3dig(0, 3, ',')} " $`)
      console.log(pricetag[key] * ctx.session.quantity[key]);
      ctx.session.sumtotalprice = ctx.session.sumtotalprice + 
      ctx.session.totalprice[key];

    }
  }
}

// task 3
ctx.telegram.sendMessage(MasterID, `⭐⭐⭐end of order⭐⭐⭐`)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please label the three tasks?

Comment: @JoelCDoyle sorry , i Correct it

Answer (score 0):

Since [`sendMessage`](http://telegraf.js.org/telegram.html#sendmessage) returns a promise, you can use `.then()` to wait for promise to resolve:

```
ctx.telegram.sendMessage(MasterID, `⭐⭐⭐new order⭐⭐⭐`).then(function(response) {
  for (var key in pricetag) {
    if (pricetag.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if ((pricetag[key] * ctx.session.quantity[key]) != 0) {

        ctx.reply(`" ${key} " , " ${ctx.session.quantity[key]} " |  " ${ctx.session.totalprice[key].format3dig(0, 3, ',')} " $`)
        console.log(pricetag[key] * ctx.session.quantity[key]);
        ctx.session.sumtotalprice = ctx.session.sumtotalprice + 
        ctx.session.totalprice[key];

      }
    }
  }

  ctx.telegram.sendMessage(MasterID, `⭐⭐⭐end of order⭐⭐⭐`)
});
```

The `for` loop is synchronous, so there is nothing special to do after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot , What if we have 3 or more  for loops , does for return promises too ?

Comment: No. `for` loops are synchronous. They execute in the order they are written. No need to use promises

Comment: Is There any references which elements are synchronous and which are asynchronous ?